# DEAP: Genetic algorithm - eval function

Tags: python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, deap

I am a beginner in Python and DEAP and I am trying to understand the evaluatiobn function for the TSP from: https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/ga/tsp.py

```
def evalTSP(individual):
    distance = distance_map[individual[-1]][individual[0]]
    for gene1, gene2 in zip(individual[0:-1], individual[1:]):
        distance += distance_map[gene1][gene2]
    return distance,
```

On `distance = distance_map[individual[-1]][individual[0]]`
The `[individual[-1]][individual[0]]` means the difference between the previous and the current individual positions?

On `for gene1, gene2 in zip(individual[0:-1], individual[1:])`
Which means the values `0:1` and `1:` of individual?

Comment: This is actually two different questions that each already have an answer on site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `individual` is represented as an `array`. `individual[-1]` and `individual[0]` refer respectively to the last and the first gene of the individual (i.e element in the array). So `distance_map[individual[-1]][individual[0]]` is the distance between these two genes as stored in the DistanceMatrix.

`individual[0:-1]` returns an array with all the genes of `individual` except for the last one. `individual[1:]` returns an array with all the genes of `individual` except for the first one.